# Textbox only converter

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, converters

I am making a temperature converter in vb.net for my assignment. I know the conversion method and so on.. but the problem is, I need to only use two textboxes. One for Celsius and one for farenheit. Whenever I update the textbox for celsius, the changes on textbox should also happen, and when I change the value for farenheit, the celsius textbox should also change depending on the value for farenheit. What method should I do?

This is the current one im working on..

```
 Class Form1
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If TextBox1.Focus() Then
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox2.Text = (TextBox1.Text - 32) / 1.8
    ElseIf TextBox2.Focus() Then
        TextBox1.Clear()

        TextBox1.Text = (TextBox2.Text * 1.8) + 32
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should explain what are you using for your app. WinForms, WPF, ASP,NET, Xamarin.....?

Comment: Sorry for being new in programming. WinForms..

Comment: The Winforms TextBox has a TextChanged event called by the engine everytime the content of the textbox changes. You should start from here or you can use a more lazy approach using the Validating event handler to perform your calculations everytime the focus leaves the textbox. Please show your efforts to get more help

Comment: And, as a hint, make sure that a change in one text box doesn't fire off a change in the other, which fires off a change in the first (lather-rinse-repeat).  If you haven't noticed, what people are saying is "write your app, find a problem, ask us how to solve it".  Don't just ask "hey, I have some homework, can you do it for me?"

Comment: can my topic removed from on hold now?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting some code.  This is the way I'd do it (after wiring up `TextChanged` event handlers for both text boxes):

```
Private DegreesCChanging As Boolean = False
Private DegreesFChanging As Boolean = False

Private Sub DegreesF_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DegreesF.TextChanged
    If Not DegreesFChanging Then
        Dim Temperature As Double
        DegreesCChanging = True
        If Double.TryParse(DegreesF.Text, Temperature ) Then
            DegreesC.Text = ((Temperature - 32.0) / 9.0 * 5.0).ToString("0.##")
        Else
            DegreesC.Text = String.Empty
        End If
        DegreesCChanging = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DegreesC_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DegreesC.TextChanged
    If Not DegreesCChanging Then
        Dim Temperature As Double
        DegreesFChanging = True
        If Double.TryParse(DegreesC.Text, Temperature ) Then
            DegreesF.Text = (Temperature / 5.0 * 9.0 + 32.0).ToString("0.##")
        Else
            DegreesF.Text = String.Empty
        End If
        DegreesFChanging = False
    End If
End Sub
```

There are a few things to note.

- I'm using the `TextChanged` event - as soon as the user types
  something into either text box, the world starts changing
- I use `double.TryParse` to convert the number to a string. If I can't figure out what's going on (i.e., the `TryParse` call returns `False`), I stick an empty string in the other text box.  It works quite well.
- When the user types something into a text box, it causes a `TextChanged` event that forces new text into the other text box - which will result in a `TextChanged` event for that control.  I use two Boolean flags to prevent this.
- I use a custom numeric format string on my ToString calls to limit
  the precision to two decimal places.